# Continuity and Metric Spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

How do I show that the function $f:X \to \mathbb R$ given by $$f(x)=\frac{d(a,x)}{d(a,b)}$$ is continuous.

Given that $(X,d)$ is a metric space, and $a,b$ are distinct points in $X$.

Comment: $d(a,b)$ is just a positive real number, so it suffices to show $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $d(a,x)$ is continuous, and I'm pretty sure that has been asked and answered here before.

Answer (score 2):

If $d(x,y)<d(a,b)\cdot\varepsilon$ then
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| = \left|\frac{d(a,x)}{d(a,b)} - \frac{d(a,y)}{d(a,b)}\right| \le \frac{d(x,y)}{d(a,b)}<\varepsilon.
$$
The first inequality follows from two instances of the triangle inequality: $d(a,x)+d(x,y)\ge d(a,y)$ and $d(a,y)+d(y,x)\ge d(a,x)$.

So given $\varepsilon>0$, let $\delta =d(a,b)\cdot\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known, and easy to prove, that $d:X\times X\to \mathbb R$, the distance function in any metric space, is uniformly continuous. In particular then, the function $d(a,-):X\to \mathbb R$ is continuous, and (since $d(a,b)\ne 0$), so is the function you mention.